# maven-jetty plugin not using correct paths

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, pathname

I am using the jetty-maven plugin to deploy a web-app for integration testing. I have a project which consists of a two POMs. One in the root, and one in a directory in the project root (call this the webapp directory). When I run the integration test from maven (which uses the jetty-maven plugin), in  the webapp directory, it works perfectly fine. However, when I run it from the root directory, it goes inside the webapp directory and runs the test but for some reason it gets the paths wrong. (As a result, all resources cannot be found).

It concatenates the root directory path to the webapp resources path. It also does not understand the dot operator in a path.

For example: if it was to look for "./resources/resource.xml"

It would work fine if the test was run from the webapp directory, however if run from the root directory it will make the path: "c:/project/./resources/resource.xml". It is the jetty-maven plugin that is doing this but I am not sure why.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here is relevant part of my webapp directory POM

```
              <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                   <webApp>${basedir}/target/webappSNAPSHOT.war</webApp>
                   <extraClasspath>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</extraClasspath>
                   <testClassesDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testClassesDirectory>
                   <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
                   <stopPort>9929</stopPort>
                   <stopKey>stopKey</stopKey>

              </configuration>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a snippet of your pom.xml with jetty plugin configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you just need to specify ${basedir} in your web app resources path.