# Unable to load external spring config files with jetty maven plugin

Tags: spring, maven, jetty

I try to launch a webapp with jetty-maven-plugin as in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin. But I want to externalize my environment configuration files.
Here is my project hierachy:

```
myapp-webapp
- src
- - test
- - - ressources
- - - java
- - main
- - - ressources
- - - java
- - - webapp
- - - - WEB-INF
- - - - META-INF
- - - - templates
- - - - ressources
- - - - index.xhtml
+ target (I don't detail it)
- configuration
- - local
- - - databaseLocal.properties
- - - ... others config files
- - dev
- - test
- - prod
```

And here is my pom file:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>myapp-work</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>!env</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                        <extraClasspath>configuration/local/</extraClasspath>
                    </webApp>
                    <scanTargetPatterns>
                    <scanTargetPattern>
                      <directory>configuration/local/</directory>
                      <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                      </includes>
                    </scanTargetPattern>
                  </scanTargetPatterns>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                    ...
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            ...
        <plugins>
```

And I am facing to this error
2012-07-04 10:33:26.460:WARN::Failed startup of context JettyWebAppContext@29b829b8@29b829b8/,file:/C:/DEV/RTCworkspace/myapp/myapp-webapp/src/main/webapp/,file:/C:/DEV/RTCworkspace/myapp/myapp-webapp/src/main/webapp/
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [databaseLocal.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I found a lot of information but nothing works:
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin
- [Cant find config files in Jetty + Spring + Tiles deployement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896694/cant-find-config-files-in-jetty-spring-tiles-deployement)
- [maven-jetty plugin not using correct paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427600/maven-jetty-plugin-not-using-correct-paths)

I try also:
${basedir}/${externalConfiguration.directory}

Here is an extract of startup log (my webapp name is cct, i replace it until now):

```
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\src\main\webapp does not exist. Defaulting to C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\configuration\local\database.properties
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\configuration\local\databaseLocal.properties
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\configuration\local\efrit-security.properties
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\configuration\local\efrit.properties
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\configuration\local\efrit_logback.xml
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\configuration\local\ldap.properties
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\configuration\local\logback.properties
[INFO] Adding extra scan target from pattern: C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\configuration\local\logback.xml
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/C:/DEV/RTCworkspace/cct/cct-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\DEV\RTCworkspace\cct\cct-webapp\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Starting jetty 7.1.6.v20100715 ...2012-07-04 11:16:56.349:INFO::jetty-7.1.6.v20100715
```

So he says, he see my config file but he is unable to read it.

Comment: DataSourceLocal is loaded from <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:databaseLocal.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
<directory>configuration/local/</directory>
```

To:

```
<directory>${basedir}/configuration/local</directory>
```

Comment: J'ai essayé comme je le disais dans le message au dessus. Finalement j'ai trouvé, ca venait d'une bean non loader car le profiles n'était pas définit.

Comment: Yeah... Well, try setting both the `<directory/>` in the `<scanTargetPattern>` and the `<extraClasspath/>` to point to `${basedir}/configuration/local`. Also, try running Maven with `-X` and paste the part which is displayed by the Jetty plugin.

Comment: thanks for you help, I found the problem. It's du too spring 3.1 profil wich hide a bean who load the conf file. I try with -x now because i don't know this option. Thanks again

Comment: `-X` will run Maven in debug mode, showing you lots and lots of output. It will enable debug logging for all the plugins and you'll be able to (hopefully) spot a cause.

Answer (score 0):

I try the precedent answer and it's not working.
In fact , I found the problem. A profil hide a bean wich load this file. I had the profile and it's work well.
It's an impact to spring 3.1 migration.